# Deserialize a single DateTime object with JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

**Context**

The line `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now)` gives the following result:

> "2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00"

However when I try to deserialize this JSON string to a DateTime with the line: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00")`

it gives an `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` with the following message:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 2. Path '', line 1, position 1.

**What else I've tried so far**

> "2018-05-25T07:59:27"

causes the very same exception

**Question**

Having the datetime string in JSON serialized format, I would like to have a `DateTime` variable and the correct value in it. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: If Serialize can use a default, then Deserialize should use a very same default

Comment: A [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string literal must be quoted, so you need to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00\"")`.  It's easy to confuse the quotations for the c# string literal (which are **not** part of the JSON) with quotes that need to be included in the JSON string.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgQ2cl

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it works. That's a real answer. You should post it. (Now I remember, once I learned the very same lesson :-), but it seems repeating is the mother of all knowledge.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), a JSON string literal must be quoted:

> A `string` is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.
>
> [image]

Thus, to be valid JSON, your c# string literal must include the surrounding double quotes, like so:

```
var dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00\"");
```

It's easy to confuse the outermost quotes, which are part of the c# language and delimit the string in your c# code but are not included in the string itself, with the inner quotes, which are part of the string literal itself.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgQ2cl).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` looks like it wants a JSON *object* rather than just any JSON *value*. (It's a shame that `SerializeObject` doesn't always produce an object, but...)

You can parse it like this:

```
DateTime dt = new JValue("2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00").ToObject<DateTime>();
```

Or (equivalently? I'm not entirely sure):

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) new JValue("2018-05-25T07:59:27.2175427+02:00");
```

There may be a better way of doing so, but that at least works.