# Converting JSON Date & Time to Normal Date & Time in C#

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to convert a JSON time to normal and store it in a string in C#.

**Here is my code :**

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string jsonDateTime = "2020-04-27T17:35:15-07:00";

string normalDateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonDateTime).ToString();
```

**I receive this error code :**

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: T. Path '', 
line 1, position 10.
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You should use DateTime.Parse

Comment: Write a test program. Use the NewtonSoft JsonConvert code to write out an object that contains a C# DateTime. Inspect the format. Make sure you can read it back in. Then look at Javascript's ToJSON function on the Date type. See what it does.

Comment: Your JSON string needs to be surrounded by quotes, like so: `"\"2020-04-27T17:35:15-07:00\""`  If it's not surrounded by quotes, it's not a valid JSON string.  See: [Deserialize a single DateTime object with JsonConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522936/3744182) which looks to be an identical question.