# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string> throws an exception on a simple string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Why does the following code

```
string x = "Some text.";
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(x);
```

throw this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 1, position 1.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
> at TestStuff2.Program.Main(String[] args)

As far as I know, strings are valid JSON, and [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) agrees with me.

Could this be an encoding issue?

Note that this works if I change the value of x to a number.
For example:

```
string x = "100";
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(x);
```

Works just fine.

Comment: _"and JSONLint agrees with me"_ - Are your sure?  Pasting `Some text.` into JSONLint  I get: `Error: Parse error on line 1:Some text.^Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`.   Strings might be valid but they need to be enclosed in a correct JSON payload which I don't believe yours is.  I don't see any `[` or `]`

Comment: You've just made me think of something actually. If you use "Some text." (with the quotation marks) on JSONLint it works. I wonder if this is something to do with it expecting the quotation marks in the object too.

Comment: Haha yep. That was it. Thank you. I'll submit an answer now.

Comment: _"with the quotation marks"_ - Yes I get that too. Odd.  Wonder why it works without [ ]

Comment: Not a problem good sir :)

Comment: Real question is why would want to deserialize a string to a string? it already is a string....

Comment: It's for a generic deserializer middle layer between a cache and calling code, so we cache as serialized JSON, then deserialize when we want it back. I was just playing around with it and noticed some weirdness with strings, but not with more complex objects.

Comment: Basically the same issue as [Deserialize a single DateTime object with JsonConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522936/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it. Turns out that it was to do with quotation marks:

```
string x = "\"Some text.\"";
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(x);
```

Works fine, since the Deserializer expects strings to start with quotation marks. But the string I was passing into the Deserializer didn't start with any.

So I was originally trying to deserialize:

```
Some text.
```

Which is not valid JSON. So instead I want to deserialize:

```
"Some text."
```

Which *is* valid JSON.